# Trouble on initializing a factory object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0, `rspec-rails 2` and `Factory` gems. I have some trouble related to the validation process when I state a Factory object for an `Account` class.

In the model file I have:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :name, ..., :password

  validates :name,
    :presence => true

  ...

  validates :password,
    :presence => true
end
```

In the factory file I have:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account, do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Foo #{n}"}
    ...
    password 'psw_secret'
    association :user
  end

  factory :user do
    auth 'registered'
  end
end
```

When in the spec file I state `let!(:account) { Factory(:account) }` it works as expected but when I use the following:

```
let!(:user) { Factory(:user, :account => Factory(:account)) }
```

I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: let!(:user) { Factory(:user, :account => Factory(:account)) }
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Account password can not be blank, Account is invalid
```

***Why*** I get that error? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you please update with your `:user` factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it the other way around:

```
@user = Factory(:user)
@account = Factory(:account, :user => @user)
```

The relation is defined on `account`, not on `user`.
Hope this helps.